# How to search in multiple searching boxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I search using 2 or more searching boxes at the same time? I did sth like this:

View:

```
<th>
  <p>
      Nr account: @Html.TextBox("Account")
      <input type="button" id="search" value="Search" />
  </p>

  <p>
      Nr invoice: @Html.TextBox("Invoice")
      <input type="button" id="search" value="Search" />
  </p>
</th>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#search').click(function () {

    var value = $("#Account, #Invoice").val().toLowerCase();

    $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
    });
```

Generally speaking, when I click 'Search' then table is filtered by value of first searchbox - 'Account'. I would like table to be filtered by values from both searchboxes, where is a mistake?

Comment: Hi your both button `id` are same so its working for first button not second.Instead use `class`.

Comment: @Swati it's a good point, thanks but it still doesn't work. Even when I'm passing one search box value (e.g. 'Account') to ```var value``` and click 'Search' button it doesn't work. Don't know if it works with classes.. I think also  it's sth wrong with assigning values to ```var value``` How can I invoke search function under ```.search``` button for both boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `class` selector instead of `id` and when button is clicked get both value separately and just compare both value inside `each` loop .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.search').click(function() {
//get both values
  var value = $("#Account").val().toLowerCase();
  var value2 = $("#Invoice").val().toLowerCase();
  $("#myTable tbody tr").filter(function() {
  var texts =$(this).text().toLowerCase()
  //check both condition 
    $(this).toggle(texts.indexOf(value) > -1 && (texts.indexOf(value2) > -1))
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p>
          Nr account<input type="text" id="Account">
          <input type="button" class="search" value="Search" />
        </p>

        <p>
          Nr invoice:<input type="text" id="Invoice">
          <input type="button" class="search" value="Search" />
        </p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Xavier</td>
      <td>41</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Muska</td>
      <td>38</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Swati</td>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Great, thanks Swati! Just one more question: when I additionally want to filter by selected option on dropdown list e.g.: ```@Html.DropDownList("filterList", new List<SelectListItem>{new SelectListItem { Text="", Value= "", Selected=true},new SelectListItem { Text="Payment", Value="Payment"},})``` then I add ```var value3 = $("#filterList").val();``` and check this extra condition here: ```$(this).toggle(texts.indexOf(value) > -1 && (texts.indexOf(value2) > -1 && (texts.indexOf(value3) > -1))``` Correct?

Comment: Yes you just need to add that condition . Let me know if that didn't work :)

Comment: I added ```$("#filterList:selected")``` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work along with other searchboxes, I checked it again.